# Elementary Problem on Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

If I invented a coordinate system of 3 parameters - just like in Cartesians $(x,y,z)$, should those 3 parameters have directional vectors that are mutually perpendicular?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "should"? Do they need to be perpendicular? No, assuming they are independent i.e. not redundant. Is it helpful if they are? That depends on your application.

Comment: @Brian I meant that in general are the coordinates of a system perpendicular as in Cartesians, Spherical, Plane and Cylindrical Polars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis will not, in general, be orthogonal, however, given any basis, you can produce an orthogonal basis. Having an orthogonal basis can be quite useful, but it is not necessary.